# Можно ли учить два языка программирования одновременно

Tags: c++, 1с

Можно ли учить два языка программирования одновременно? В моем случае 1С и С++.

Comment: имхо, писать вопросы в таком виде как-то неуважительно

Comment: я вопрос не корректно задал? как поправить?

Comment: "развивают язык" обычно разработчики языка. Лучше один язык сначала подучить, на второй потом перейти будет легче, иначе есть вероятность получить кашу вместо структурированных знаний. Выберите язык который вам нравится больше/с которым вы связываете свою дальнейшую деятельность и занимайтесь им.

Comment: язык программирования можно выучить за месяц-два, развивать нужно умение читать документацию.

Comment: @eicto и какой же язык программирования вы выучили за месяц-два? Турбо Паскаль по по учебнику для чайников?

Comment: @Dreamchild  js, php, erlang (частично, т.к. потратил неделю всего) обычно учу по офиц документации, по мере надобности языка как инструмента.

Comment: @elcto, С++ за пару месяцев? Не смешите мои тапочки. Только на самом-самом базовом уровне и не выше быдлокодинга. Это вам не PHP. По-настоящему С++ учится годами (я даже не имею в виду библиотеку - это отдельный разговор). Я о самом языке. Он похлеще китайского будет.

Comment: что касается С++, то поддерживаю @mikillskegg - его нужно учить несколько лет, чтобы можно было сказать, что "я его знаю". JS и PHP, конечно, значительно проще, но и их на хорошем уровне за пару месяцев не выучить. По поводу Erlang ничего сказать не могу - не знаком с ним вообще

Comment: Стандарт С++ вполне себе описан [тут](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft) мне вас реально жаль если за месяц вы не сможете осилить и понять 1500 страниц стандарта. Остальное - практика, за месяц я думаю подтянется до уровня чуть выше быдлокода.

Comment: моя позиция заключается вот в чем - пока язык не нужен - не изучай его, ато будешь как горе-ява-програмисты которые на яве клепают сайты типа "я и моя собака" а нам админам их поддерживать и деплоить

Comment: >мне вас реально жаль если за месяц вы не сможете осилить и понять 1500 страниц стандарта

@eicto, это шутка?

Comment: @eicto, @mikillskegg -- "С++ за пару месяцев" -- бред, а erlang за неделю -- нормально? Функциональный язык при наличии опыта использования императивных и отсутствии знания функциональных за неделю -- das ist fantastisch!

Практика показывает, что на поворот мозгов требуется времени намного больше (если, конечно, мозги не вращаются внутри черепа свободно)

@DreamChild в erlang'е переменные своего значения не меняют. От рождения до смерти оно у них одно.

Comment: @alexlz, как в том анекдоте: "И ты пгав".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Развивать", как вы изволили выразиться, два языка не просто реально, а даже нужно - любой хороший разработчик должен знать на приемлемом уровне несколько языков (ну хотя бы даже два). Конечно, во всей ширине и глубине много языков постигнуть не получится, но все же одним-двумя нужно владеть более чем уверенно. Более того, нередко весьма полезно взглянуть на мир под другим углом - скажем, работая с объектно-ориентированными языками, изучить функциональное программирование

Answer (score 6):

Обязательно. Знать только один 1С - это даже как-то... стыдно.

Answer (score 2):

Реально!
Если я не ошибаюсь в 1С можно писать на модифицированном C++.
На него и стоит бросить все свои силы.